# String to degree coordinate

Tags: android, location

I need to convert coordinates from Location into a String to show in a EditText. Then, I need to convert back these strings into coordinates again to set it into location object.

This is what I do:

```
String latitude = mLocation.convert(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.FORMAT_DEGREES);
String longitude = mLocation.convert(mLocation.getLongitude(), mLocation.FORMAT_DEGREES);

latitudeEditText.setText(latitude);
longitudeEditText.setText(longitude);
```

This way, I convert something like `43.56432` into `43,56432`.

Now, I need to set this value back from the EditText into Location. This is what I do:

```
String latitude = latitudeEditText.getText().toString();
String longitude = longitudeEditText.getText().toString();

mLocation.setLatitude(mLocation.convert(latitude));
mLocation.setLongitude(mLocation.convert(longitude));
```

But when `mLocation.convert(latitude)` is throwing a `IllegalArgumentException`.

In the documentation sais:

```
public static double convert (String coordinate)

Added in API level 1
Converts a String in one of the formats described by FORMAT_DEGREES, 
    FORMAT_MINUTES, or FORMAT_SECONDS into a double.

Throws
NullPointerException    if coordinate is null
IllegalArgumentException    if the coordinate is not in one of the valid formats.
```

So, this is telling me that the String isn't in DEGREE format, but this can't be, because I use booth ways the convert() method to do it right.

Comment: did you log what the output is of the original call to convert() in order to determine if indeed it is in the correct format?  If so, can you paste that log here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried a quick test and everything works as expected:

```
Location mLocation = new Location("");
mLocation.setLatitude(43.56432);

String latitude = Location.convert(mLocation.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);

Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: " + latitude);

double latitudeDouble = Location.convert(latitude);

Log.d(TAG, "Latitude double: " + latitudeDouble);
```

Output:

```
01-30 16:12:53.628: D/LocationActivity(29240): Latitude: 43.56432
01-30 16:12:53.628: D/LocationActivity(29240): Latitude double: 43.56432
```

Do you have any TextWatchers or anything other logic on your EditText that replace the period with a comma?

Also, make sure you access static fields statically.

Comment: It must be something then when pasing it form the edittext to the string. I'm trying now to replace the comma with a dot before calling to convert(). I'll post later with the result

Comment: Seems to work replacing the commas with dots before calling to convert() method